# Why does code coverage report fail on php 7.2?

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, travis-ci, php-7.2

I'm running a php build matrix on travis-ci for php 7.0 and 7.2.

https://travis-ci.org/uawcob/course-overrides/jobs/242630482

On 7.0, The tests all pass and code coverage is generated fine.

[image: php 7 screenshot passes great]

On 7.2, you can see that all the tests run and pass the same, but generating the code coverage report throws an exception which causes the whole build to **fail**.

[image: screenshot php 7.2 code coverage exception]

Why is this?

The full error stack for posterity:

> ```
> Generating code coverage report in HTML format ...PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable. in /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:895
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(735): Illuminate\Container\Container->notInstantiable('Illuminate\\Cont...')
> #1 /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('Illuminate\\Cont...')
> #2 /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(575): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('Illuminate\\Cont...')
> #3 /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(728): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
> #4 /home/travis/build/uawcob/cour in /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 895
> Fatal error: Uncaught Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable. in /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 895
> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable. in /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 895
> Call Stack:
>     3.7921    6622616   1. Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException() /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:0
>     3.7921    6622616   2. Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->getExceptionHandler() /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:80
>     3.7921    6622616   3. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:155
>     3.7921    6622616   4. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:728
>     3.7921    6622616   5. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve() /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:575
>     3.7921    6622616   6. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->build() /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:608
>     3.7921    6622728   7. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->notInstantiable() /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:735
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable. in /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:895
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(735): Illuminate\Container\Container->notInstantiable('Illuminate\\Cont...')
> #1 /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('Illuminate\\Cont...')
> #2 /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(575): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('Illuminate\\Cont...')
> #3 /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(728): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
> #4 /home/travis/build/uawcob/cour in /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 895
> Fatal error: Uncaught Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable. in /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 895
> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable. in /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 895
> Call Stack:
>     3.7929    6633672   1. Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown() /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:0
>     3.7938    6641592   2. Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException() /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:119
>     3.7938    6641592   3. Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->getExceptionHandler() /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:80
>     3.7938    6641592   4. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:155
>     3.7938    6641592   5. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:728
>     3.7938    6641592   6. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve() /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:575
>     3.7939    6641592   7. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->build() /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:608
>     3.7939    6641704   8. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->notInstantiable() /home/travis/build/uawcob/course-overrides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:735
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Looking into your code for that exact error message, [the proposed fix upstream](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/3725#discussion-diff-58023344) is to exclude the `./app/Http/routes.php` file from code-coverage:

```
...
<whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
    <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        <exclude>
            <file>./app/Http/routes.php</file>

            <!-- ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^  -->

...
```

That is from a quick look checking your projects sources of the build that fails shows that this is not yet set in the [phpunit.xml.dist](https://github.com/uawcob/course-overrides/blob/9fc11acf8544a70902f9d4c0d1b4758f67503e3c/phpunit.xml.dist) file. I can not say why this happens only in the PHP 7.2 build. So hopfully this can shed some more light and perhaps this rings a bell (e.g. different Phpunit version).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'm digging in deeper, but it seems like this was an old change that was merged, and later removed. Maybe the issue has bubbled back up again in PHP 7.2

Comment: no dice, it's still broken: https://travis-ci.org/uawcob/course-overrides/jobs/244729795